# Is "The Unsettling" inspired by "Manos: The Hands of Fate"?

Tags: inspiration, manos-the-hands-of-fate, the-unsettling

In the TV series *The Unsettling*, the plot centers around a cult that worships a deity with heavy hand symbolism, in which the members are constantly saying that "the Hands that pull the strings" have ordained things a certain way. This seems rather similar to the famously bad cult horror film *Manos: The Hands of Fate*, often called the worst film of all time, where "The Master" and his cult worship the god Manos (literally Hands), whose holy symbol is a hand. What is more, the film and the series are both set in creepy ranch houses in the American Southwest, among other similarities.

Further, as the tagline for *Manos* says, "a cult of weird, horrible people who gather beautiful women only to deface them with a burning hand." Although, publicity aside, no one was actually defaced with a burning hand in *Manos*, the members of the cult in *The Unsettling* do deface themselves with a hand brand.
There even seems to be a possible in-joke or reference to the Master with the creepy ash-man and his large black dog.

Has anyone involved with the show mentioned this as an inspiration?

Comment: Manos inspiring anything (other than perhaps how not to make a bad movie) would be pretty unsettling.

Comment: With respect to the close votes, do you think it's the movie with a vampire cult leader with the power of mind control who is immune to bullets and worships a god of primal darkness and his satyr sidekick that is not fantasy, or rather the TV show with a vengeful, telekinetic, and pyrokinetic ghost and a cursed land that drives people to evil and makes them see hallucinations? Just curious.